# If else in a single statement :scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I would like to know if there is a better way of writing the below if-else statement in a better way. This is purely for my learning

```
val tokenizationRequired = if (args(4).equals("true")) true else false

    if (tokenizationRequired) {
      primary_key                   = args(5)

      if (primary_key.equals("") || primary_key.isEmpty) {
        log info s"Primary_Key cannot be empty"
      }

      lookupPath                    = args(6)

      if (lookupPath.equals("") || lookupPath.isEmpty) {
        log info s"lookupPath cannot be empty"
      }

    }
```

Here is the case statement i tried which did not work

```
val primary_key = args(5) match {
        case " " => log info s"lookupPath cannot be empty"
        case _ => args(5)
 }
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use match case statements for the above.

Comment: I tried match but i am not able to print logs within the case statement.

Comment: Can you please provide the match case that you tried

Comment: Why not just `tokenizationRequired = args(4) == "true"`? What's the difference between `""` and `.isEmpty`? (Hint: There is none.) Why are you using string interpolation, `s"...",` when there is nothing to interpolate in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val tokenizationRequired = args(4).toBoolean
val primary_key                   = args(5)
val lookupPath                    = args(6)

if (tokenizationRequired && primary_key.isEmpty) {
  log info s"Primary_Key cannot be empty"
}

if (tokenizationRequired && lookupPath.isEmpty) {
  log info s"lookupPath cannot be empty"
}
```

> Here is the case statement i tried which did not work ...

Following works in scala 2.13+ only:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

val primary_key = arg(5)
     .tap(x => if (x.isEmpty) log info s"lookupPath cannot be empty")
```

and your version will compile with a small change:

```
val primary_key = args(5) match {
  case x if x.isEmpty => 
    log info s"lookupPath cannot be empty"
    x
  case x => x 
}
```